# TreeMap lastKey lookup time

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap, sortedmap

What is the time complexity of TreeMap.lastKey() part of the SortedMap interface?

The oracle docs mention this about TreeMaps:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

Comment: It should be O(log(n)) too. It is mostly balanced and requires going to the right always.

Comment: You can also look at the source code, to see how it's implemented. The answer would be pretty straightforward after.

Comment: I see. Is there an elegant way to always keep track of the last key/value even after deleting an object from the map? Maybe with the maps entrySet?

Comment: @ArjunPatel Is O(logn) too large? What is your usecase?

Comment: You can track the map's maximum key by wrapping / instrumenting all the map's mutation methods (don't forget the iterator's `remove()` method and the mutators of the submaps, and *their* iterators and submaps, etc.).  That's certainly not elegant, though, and it will degrade performance, especially of the multi-element removal methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the implementation in the Open JDK, it is O(log N):

```
public K lastKey() {
    return key(getLastEntry());
}
final Entry<K,V> getLastEntry() {
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    if (p != null)
        while (p.right != null)
            p = p.right;
    return p;
}
```

The `lastKey()` calls `getLastEntry()`, which continues to take the right subtree until there are no further nodes to take. Since the implementation maintains the tree in a balanced state, the number of iterations is O(log N).

Comment: It's easy to make the intuitive mistake that the last entry would be easily accessible at the "end" of the data structure. I had to remind myself that the "easily accessible" entry for a red-black tree is actually the _median_ element (i.e., the element at the root of the tree).

Answer (score 1):

If `TreeMap` can guarantee O(log(n)) for `containsKey()` (as it does), then it *should* be able to do `lastKey()` in O(log(n)) as well.  Any tree structure that can be certain to yield O(log(n)) key lookups can also support finding the maximum key in O(log(n)).

Although nothing inherently rules out a brain-dead implementation that does worse, I think it's pretty safe to discount that possibility for `java.util.TreeMap`.